# Как можно в NanoHTTPD перенаправлять все запросы на https?

Tags: java, redirect, nanohttpd

Как можно в NanoHTTPD перенаправлять все запросы на https? Если я включаю сервер предварительно вызвав makeSecure(), то обращение из браузера по адресу http://myserver дает ошибку

```
SEVERE: Could not send response to the client
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1484)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(SSLSocketImpl.java:1496)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:62)
    at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBody(NanoHTTPD.java:1620)
    at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBodyWithCorrectEncoding(NanoHTTPD.java:1593)
    at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBodyWithCorrectTransferAndEncoding(NanoHTTPD.java:1583)
    at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$Response.send(NanoHTTPD.java:1550)
    at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.execute(NanoHTTPD.java:952)
    at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$ClientHandler.run(NanoHTTPD.java:192)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

Как этого избежать?

Comment: Вам нужно поднять два сервера, один с HTTP на порту 80 (который будет генерировать редирект, подставляя в данные запроса порт 443), второй с HTTPS на порту 443, который уже будет выполнять реальную работу. Я не уверен, что физически возможно слушать оба протокола на одном сокете (можно, конечно, делать `try { readHttps() } catch (Any e) { readHttp() }`, но там очень много место для выстрела в ногу).

Comment: В NanoHttpd конструктор сервера принимает в качестве аргумента порт. Соответственно и обращаться к серверу я собираюсь      **https**://192.168.0.1:8080. Но вот что делать если пользователь в браузере набирает **http**://192.168.0.1:8080 ?

Comment: он просто не сможет подключиться

Comment: Неужели нет способа где-нибудь на уровне сокета "отлупливать нешифрованный запрос и посылать редирект"?

Comment: Каким образом вы представляете себе отделение шифрованного потока байт от нешифрованного? Повторюсь, вы можете, в теории, считывать первые несколько байт и анализировать на основе них, но это все равно выстрелит в ногу и сложно интегрируется в инфраструктуру.

Comment: Но по-моему это как-то делается на Apache, с помощью конфигов сервера

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/359465/195634 судя по всему, сам по себе апач такого не умеет